# Message queues in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, queue

General advice for a change. This is an implementation of message queues that I'm going to use for some work on an actors model library.

```
(defclass message-queue ()
  ((messages :accessor messages :initarg :messages :initform nil)
   (last-cons :accessor last-cons :initarg :last-cons :initform nil
    :documentation "Cached end of the list")
   (len :accessor len :initarg :len :initform 0
    :documentation "Cached message queue length. Modified by enqueue and dequeue")
   (lock :initform (bt:make-lock) :accessor lock
    :documentation "Lock for this message queue")
   (max-len :accessor max-len :initarg :max-len :initform nil
    :documentation "If present, queue maintains at most this many elements")
   (flag :initform (bt:make-condition-variable) :accessor flag
    :documentation "Condition variable used to notify that a message was enqueued")))

(defun make-queue (&optional max-len) 
  (make-instance 'message-queue :max-len max-len))

(defmethod full-p ((queue sized-queue))
  (with-slots (len max-len)
      (and max-len (>= len max-len))))

(defmethod empty-p ((queue message-queue)) 
  (= (len queue) 0))

(defmethod enqueue (object (queue message-queue))
  "Adds an element to the back of the given queue in a thread-safe way."
  (with-slots (lock messages max-len len flag last-cons) queue
    (with-lock-held (lock)
      (let ((o (list object)))
    (cond ((empty-p queue)
           (setf messages o 
             last-cons messages
             len 1))
          ((full-p queue)
           (pop messages)
           (setf (cdr last-cons) o 
             last-cons o))
          (t (setf (cdr last-cons) o
               last-cons o)
         (incf len)))))
    (condition-notify flag)
    messages))

(defmethod dequeue ((queue message-queue) &optional (timeout 0))
  "Pops a message from the given queue in a thread-safe way.
If the target queue is empty, blocks until a message arrives.
If timeout is not zero, errors after timeout."
  (with-slots (messages lock flag len) queue 
    (with-timeout (timeout)
      (with-lock-held (lock)
    (unless messages (condition-wait flag lock))
    (decf len)
    (pop messages)))))

(defmethod dequeue-no-hang ((queue message-queue))
  "Pops a message from the given queue in a thread-safe way.
If the target queue is empty, returns NIL.
The second value specifies whether an item was found in queue (this is meant
to disambiguate the situation where a queue contains the message NIL)"
  (with-slots (messages lock flag len) queue
    (with-lock-held (lock)
      (if messages
      (progn
        (decf len)
        (values (pop messages) t))
      (values nil nil)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

I noticed you defined full read/write accessors on all the slots on your message queue class, yet you bypass all of that and just use with-slots. Are you planning on exporting those accessors as part of the API? It seems like you wouldn't want to encourage people to monkey with those slot values, so probably not. You could also drop :initarg from everything but max-len.